# ArrayResolver in castle windsor behaves strangely

Tags: castle-windsor

Im using windsor along with the subresolver ArrayResolver and works great besides one thing.

Here the ArrayResolver works the the way it supposed to work.

```
class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
  public SomeClass(ISomeDependency[] dependecies)
  {}
}
```

This thing does not work

```
ISomeDependency[] = container.Resolve<ISomeDependency[]>().Cast<ISomeDependency>().ToArray()
```

, and this is why im asking, why isn't the sub resolver involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it's a sub **Dependency** resolver - it will resolve **dependencies** of the component you pull, not the component itself.

For that use

`container.ResolveAll<ISomeDependency>();`

Comment: Ok, thats the way I solved my problem, thanks for the explanation Krzysztof.